# npm install packages succesful, but don't import any component from those packages

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm in the middle of a react-native project. I've installed, linked and used many packages along time. But now installing packages by npm is being succesful, it is added at package.json, but when I import some feature from package to my project files, app crashes showing messages like:

```
"undefined is not a object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.array') 

 "undefined is not a object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.bool') 

 "undefined is not a object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.object')
```

Example, when I install react-native-modal-picker:

```
> C:\Users\Taylon\reactive-native-projects\gps7plus>npm install
> react-native-modal
> -picker --save npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^
> 4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fse vents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
> OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
> 1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} )
> 
> + react-native-modal-picker@0.0.16 added 1 package in 19.823s
```

Could these WARN messages mess something?

Linking (any messages):

```
C:\Users\Taylon\reactive-native-projects\gps7plus>react-native link react-native
-modal-picker
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Taylon\reactive-native-projects\gps7pl
us\node_modules (31ms)

C:\Users\Taylon\reactive-native-projects\gps7plus>
```

Importing...

```
import ModalPicker from 'react-native-modal-picker';
```

I've not even instance this yet. And so red screen:

```
"undefined is not a object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.array')
```

Is there any method that allow to check npm errors? Or some to verify if packages are really installed?

Comment: Hi! Please don't post pictures of code or errors, it makes them unsearchable and uncrawlable by search engines (for one thing). Can you replace the images with text versions?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, Im going to fix it.

Comment: Taylon, thank you! It really makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module [`react-native-modal-picker`](https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker) has not been updated since long, and [`PropTypes`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) have been moved to a separate package since version `React` `v15.5` as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

You can find the proof in their [index.js](https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker/blob/master/index.js) file

```
import React,{
    PropTypes
} from 'react';
```

Therefore you need to find an alternative to it. I would recommend you to use this package [`react-native-actionsheet`](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet), since it is cross platform, and provides the same function.